# Optimize deployment cycle for development

Tags: maven, jboss, seam, jboss7.x, seam3

I use Seam3 + maven + jboss7 combination in my development. Would it be possible to optimize the loadup time when I do

```
mvn clean package jboss-as:redeploy
```

Currently this takes over 20 seconds with core2duo with an SSD (Mac Air).

In my workflow, it's common to make a lot of small changes and then redeploy and see changes. It's quite a big bottleneck with current setup, and it breaks my flow.

1. Would it be possible to do proper hot-deployment over my configuration?
2. Is there parameters for making startup faster when developing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found about [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/). It's a gift that I would not have expected to fall upon me. This supports my workflow and makes me much more efficient. If you need hot-deployment, try it out!

Answer (score 0):

There is no hot-deployment. I'm not sure why it would be taking 20 seconds either. I get around a 3 second start-up time with JBoss AS7 and my deployment times are around 1 second maven deployments.

Is the server running locally or on a different machine? It could be the time it takes over the network.

You can write custom deployment scripts or write custom Java code to deploy applications as well.

Comment: I have a local server. See my own answer which solved my problem. With JRebel I have hot-deployment now (yes, even with Jboss AS7).

Comment: Yes. I've heard great things about JRebel. Thanks for the update.